# Why does the benefit of using margin diminish over time?

Tags: calculation, leverage

When using margin to invest, your exposure is increased but there are fees associated with doing so. The future value of an investment given an annual return rate and margin loan interest rate can be calculated using:

```
p*l*(1+r)^n-sum i*p*(l-1)*(1+r)^k, k=0 to n-1
```

where p is the principal, r is the annual return, l is the leverage factor (ie. 2 would mean half the money is borrowed), n is the number of years the investment is held and i is the interest rate on the loan. For simplicity, interest is paid at the end of the year.

I have two questions:

1. Is this formula correct?
2. Why does the annualized return tend towards r as n increases? For example:

when n is 3 (and p is 1, l is 1.6, i is 0.03, r is 10%...)

```
(1.6*(1+0.1)^3-sum 0.03*(1.6-1)*(1+0.1)^k, k=0 to 3-1)^(1/3)=1.274
```

when n is 10000

```
(1.6*(1+0.1)^10000-sum 0.03*(1.6-1)*(1+0.1)^k, k=0 to 10000-1)^(1/10000)=1.1
```

It seems confusing that the benefit of using leverage diminishes the longer the holding period (if the math is correct).

Edit: I think the original loan amount must be subtracted from the future value.

Comment: How I wish that this site had LaTeX support to display all this math properly.

Comment: The formularization is above my pay grade.  However, the benefit of using leverage should not  diminish over time because in your hypothetical, the margin loan amount is constant as is the borrow rate.  Both investments would grow at the same respective rates.

Answer (score -1):

Basically there are two way you can calculate return of your investment
first being
ROI= Net Return  on  Investment / Cost  of  Investment × 100%

second

ROI= Final Value of Investment − Initial Value of Investment / Cost of Investment × 100%

Assume an investor bought 10000 shares of the some company. at $100 per share. One year later, the investor sold the shares for $120. The investor earned dividends of $5000 over the one-year holding period. The investor also spent a total of $1200 on trading commissions in order to buy and sell the shares.

The ROI for this investor can be calculated as follows:

ROI = ([($120 - $100) * 10000 + $5000- $120] ÷ ($100 * 10000)

Comment: The question is about the return of a cash investment versus the return of borrowing money (margin).  Your answer does not address this.